# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, maven-plugin

I am using Maven 3.0.5 and Spring Tool Source 3.2 with Maven plugin
installed. When I try to do 'Run As---> Maven install', I am getting
the following error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) on project mavencxf: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources: org/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Mindbowser-MB/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Mindbowser-MB/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/Mindbowser-MB/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/Mindbowser-MB/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/Mindbowser-MB/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/Mindbowser-MB/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/Mindbowser-MB/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.5/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/Mindbowser-MB/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0/maven-filtering-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/Mindbowser-MB/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.4/plexus-build-api-0.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/Mindbowser-MB/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.13/plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

Comment: Sounds like a mismatch between your maven installations, perhaps. Check your maven settings in eclipse. Does mvn install work on command line. If not, what does mvn -e install provide.

Comment: Apart from the above check why are you using an older version of maven-resources-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

`A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources: org/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner`

The resources plugin is missing a dependency; But it should download it automatically,... are you in **offline** mode? If you are go online *once* and execute it, it should download the missing dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the repositories defined in the POM.XML file.  I removed them so that it would use the default repo and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once when something went wrong with the repository, and then even if I ran maven again, it still failed.

**Solution**:

1. delete maven repo  *~/.m2/repository*
2. and then re-build

It works for me.